# Wrong redirectTo with lazyLoadmodules

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

The problem
I want to redirect to pages when I access localhost: 4200 but redirects to localhost: 4200 / login always.

I have 2 lazy load modules, each lazy module have childRoutes I dont understand at all what is doing to redirect always to login.

app.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'pages',
    loadChildren: './static/static.module#StaticModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: './core/auth/auth.module#AuthModule',
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' }
];
```

static.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: StaticComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'home',
      pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
      path: 'home',
      component: HomeComponent,
      data: { title: 'menu.home' }
    },
    {
      path: 'features',
      component: FeaturesComponent,
      data: { title: 'menu.features' }
    },
    {
      path: '**',
      component: NotFoundComponent,
    }
  ]
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class StaticRoutingModule { }
```

auth.routing.module.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: NbAuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: SignInComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: SignUpComponent
      }
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: are you using the router to redirect within your components somwhere? maybe a guard?

Comment: As long as your routes seems like don't have any guards or resolvers I agree with @JasonWhite - there should be some redirect inside component logic.

Answer (score 0):

children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      }

This piece of code is doing the redirect to /login page right?

Comment: yes but that show me blank NbAuthComponent so it redirect to that component ... https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/auth/custom-auth-components#setup-auth-container

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I import authModule in my appModule, is strange that angular didnt trigger an error, but actually I just delete the import module and it's works as expected.